# Android Xml data parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse XML and display it into list view but after running the app nothing happen the list display but not with XML data. I don't know if I missing something please can help me.

**MainActivity class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = null; // getting XML
        try {
            xml = parser.getXmlFormUrl(URL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.activity_main,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        // selecting single ListView item

    }


}
```

**XmlParser class**

```
    public class XMLParser {
        String result;
        public String getXmlFormUrl(String link) throws IOException{
        URL url=new URL(link.toString());
        HttpURLConnection UrlConnection= (HttpURLConnection)     url.openConnection();
        int status=UrlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(status==200){
            InputStream inputStream=UrlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF8"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append((line+"\n"));
            }
            result=stringBuilder.toString();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return  result;
    }
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        // return DOM
        return doc;
    }
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

    public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="android.prgguru.com.xmlparsingg.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**after this line I think the list should  display with XML data** but nothing happens

```
 myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**ids.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="desciption" type="id" />
    <item name="cost" type="id" />
    <item name="name" type="id" />
    <item name="List" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: are you getting data when you call this line xml = parser.getXmlFormUrl(URL);

Comment: yes i am getting the xml data when I call this line xml = parser.getXmlFormUrl(URL);

Comment: can you show your activity_main file? and what is R.id.name

Comment: @MustanserIqbal i updated my code for activity_main file

Comment: @MustanserIqbal i update my code with logcat can you please tell me what happens

Comment: aahh i think your there is something wrong with your parser. i tried but its not working.. and this error shows that you are trying to insert data in table. and your data is empty. check you first line. there is no data found to insert in DB

Comment: i don't have DB i am trying to read xml data file  then display it in list-view

Comment: then there is something wrong with your parser. try to download the whole project given on androidhive site. and then run. hopefully it will work. you must be missing something.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer  this error message when i am run the app

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/  this example that i try it

Comment: on which line you are getting this error.

Comment: setListAdapter(adapter); this line

Comment: @MustanserIqbal i think the exception with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: i am trying to download this code. but unfortunately its not downloading. i'll try it later and will let you know whats the problem

Comment: OK many thanks i will wait you

Comment: i have tried the code and it is working fine.. let me add the answer you can just copy paste. and then let me know if it is working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create **main.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

creare **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#dc6800"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
        <!-- Description label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desciption"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <!-- Linear layout for cost and price Cost: Rs.100 -->
        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Cost Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Cost: " >
        </TextView>
        <!-- Price Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac" 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="left">
        </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

create **MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

create **XMLParser.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

all the code copied from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) you just need to copy paste the above code and then let me know if it is working or not

Comment: i want to do something else but i don't know how i want to get attribute values if the element have attribute

Comment: what you want to do.. what is your link

Comment: i have xml file has attributes of xml element you want to mention xml file here ?

Comment: i want to display like last example with list-view but with attributes

Comment: i update my question with xml file that i want to display in list-view with attributes

Comment: we can discuss  on mail please need your help if you don't mind

Comment: can you share the link for this xml file?

Comment: i don't have the link i can post the xml file here ? but it is big

Comment: upload it somewhere and share the link

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573011/xml-dom-parser-then-display-the-result-with-list-view)  this the link for the example that i wan to do

Comment: You got the example ?

Comment: this is another question posted by you. can you sahre your xml file. so i can tell you how to read the tags

Comment: your xml file is not valid.

Comment: how , is missing some thing or what ?

Comment: check your above file here http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VwzuCpx97IU

Comment: i got the link. will check it later on and will let you know

Comment: No i don't know i am beginner with android tell me what is easy way

Comment: (mustnaer.iqbal1) i didn't find you  on skype

Comment: mohamedhashim  on skype

Comment: i added you on skype